# how to apply animation on android activity

Tags: animation, android-animation

i am working on app in which i need some animation on activity i cannot find
any solution. please any one help me

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener {

    TextView tv;
    Animation animFadein;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.fade_in);

    }

}
```

Comment: your question is not clear but i post my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animations can be performed through either XML or android code. In this tutorial many of animation are explained that how to do animations using XML notations for an activity.

[**tutorial link**](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/)
and [**source code**](http://rehman-furniture.com/attaullahcs/stackdir/AndroidAnimationsUsingXML.zip)

[image]